# How to make the maven failsafe plugin split integration tests into two groups?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, testng

I have a multi module maven project

- JAR module A
- JAR module B depends on A
- WAR module C depends on B

Each of the modules has three types of tests.

- Unit tests that don't depend on any external resources being present
- Database integration tests that only depend on external database being present
- REST api tests that depend on the application running in tomcat before they can run

I would like maven to execute the tests in the following order.

1. All unit tests for modules A,B,C
2. All database tests for modules A,B,C
3. All REST api tests for module A,B,C

I know how to use the surefire and the failsafe plugins to separate the unit tests from the integration tests. However i don't know how to make the failsafe plugin split the integration tests into two groups the database tests and the rest api tests.

**How can the failsafe plugin be configured to split integration tests into groups that can be run separately?**

All tests are written with TestNG.

Comment: Have you defined appropriate groups via TestNG?

Comment: Yes there are TestNG groups defined, but the tests of different types are in different classes with different naming conventions.